# Geometry and angle 'quad'sectors

Tags: contest-math, angle

In $\bigtriangleup ABC$, the points $A_2, A_3, A_4$ are chosen inside the triangle so that
$\angle ABA_2 = \angle A_2BA_3 = \angle A_3BA_4 = \angle A_4BC.$ If $A, A_2, A_3, A_4$ are collinear,
find $\angle BA_2A_3$ given that $\angle A = 50.$

$A. 85/2$

$B. 40$

$C. 75/2$

D. Not uniquely determined

E. None of given

Here's my diagram (letting $A, A_2, A_3, A_4$ be on $AC$):
[image]

So I first let $\angle ABA_2=x^{\circ}$. Then, $\angle C=130-4x^{\circ}$. Then, $\angle ABA_{i}=130-(i-1)x^{\circ}$. So, $\angle BA_2A_3=50+x^{\circ}$. That narrows it down to D or E, and I guessed D, since it looked like $x$ had no restrictions. However, the answer was E.

Please post a solution. Thanks.

Comment: well for one we can show that $x$ can't exceed 32.5 and is likely much less simply due to sum of angles of a triangle in the plane.

Comment: but that doesn't show that it only has one solution

Comment: still no progress, anyone here

Comment: I don't understand why you say $x$ has no restrictions. $x$ is exactly $\angle ABC/4$, isn't it? Each triangle has a uniquely determined $x$. Even with this you'd need to consider the case where $A_1, A_2, A_3$ aren't in $\overline{AC}$.

Comment: but it's asking for ALL triangles, would that mean $\angle ABC$ is constant?

Comment: Why do you think it's asking for all triangles? It says "In $\triangle ABC$...", which means that particular triangle, that sentence fixes the location of $A, B$ and $C$, and so it determines its angles too. The term $\angle ABC/4$ is uniquely determined for each triangle, even when its value could be different for each triangle. That's my interpretation at least, I agree that it could be better worded though.

Comment: but like what if there are different triangles ABC

Comment: like more than one

Comment: I honestly don't know. It seems that what the author wanted to say is "Once you fix $(A,B,C)$ and $A_2, A_3$ and $A_4$, is the angle $\angle BA_2A_3$ uniquely determined?" which seems a really silly question because you can just say "Yes, because $B, A_2$ and $A_3$ are determined". And while that's true, the question is not explicit and could be a bit ambiguous, just as your questions prove. But if the answer is $E$, that's the only thing I can think of.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103549/discussion-between-asdf334-and-acheca).